# Disable automatic indentation in TeXShop source code

Tags: sourcecode

While writing source code in TeXShop, hitting enter normally causes the source to start a new line which is automatically indented as much as the previous line. I'm well aware that the automatic indentation is sometimes desirable, but other times it isn't. How can I disable it?

Comment: Perhaps I should add that control-enter creates a new line without the indentation.

Comment: Can you give an example where you would use this? Note that if you auto-wrap a paragraph there is no indent for the auto-wrapped lines. Also, there is the `Source->Unindent menu command (not bound to a shortcut) and, if you end each line with an Return it will continue that way.

Comment: I'm editing a large file (complied jointly with coauthors with differing TeXing styles) in which I rarely want new lines to start where the previous line started. So this feature, instead of being useful, is quite annoying.

Comment: If you don’t add tab characters yourself set `Tab Size` under the `Editor` tab of `TeXShop->Preferences` to 0. Then normal indents should go away.